# Grid related UI design question

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Grid related UI design question

I want some 16-grid (4 rows and 4 columns) user interface, and fill the grid with some round shapes. I also want to use the MouseOver, mouse left button down, and Mouse Left Button Up events to set the state of grids as selected or not selected.

My questions:
1. How fill the grid with some round shapes?  by SetColumn and  SetRow? 
2. How to make the grids respond to the mouse please?

Thanks

```
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you initialize the grid in code instead of XAML. Since you need pretty repetitive stuff (4×4 shapes, each one hooked up to the same event handlers) you definitely don't want to do that in XAML.

You can use [Grid.SetRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx) and [Grid.SetColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx) to position the controls you create.

You can then use the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx) and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave.aspx) events for hover effects (or even create triggers based on that).